# Aborting with error: Error Domain=BSTransactionError Code=3 "Transaction aborted

Tags: objective-c

> Aborting with error:
>   Error Domain=BSTransactionError Code=3 "Transaction aborted. (parent
>   transaction)" UserInfo={error-reason=parent transaction,
>   precipitating-error=Error Domain=BSTransactionError Code=1
>   "Transaction failed. Child transaction failed:
>    (child transaction)"
>   UserInfo={error-reason=child transaction, precipitating-error=Error
>   Domain=BSTransactionError Code=1 "Transaction failed. no client
>   provider for client with bundleID xxx.xxx.xxx (scene update failed)"
>   UserInfo={error-reason=scene update failed,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Transaction failed. no client provider for
>   client with bundleID xxx.xxx.xxx (scene update failed),
>   error-description=no client provider for client with bundleID
>   xxx.xxx.xxx, transaction=},
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Transaction failed. Child transaction failed:
>    (child transaction),
>   error-description=Child transaction failed SystemUI unknown
>   identifier: ‘xxx.xxx.xxx’

Answer (score 0):

I did also face the same problem this morning. I found my app's distribution provisioning profile was expired yesterday. I renewed the provisioning profile and rebuilt the app to make it work again.